# Autofac multiple implementations

Tags: c#, autofac

I wanted to expand on the quick start example for Autofac. What I want to do is instead of writing to the console I want to write to a file. I created a new class that implements IOutput and it writes to a file correctly.

```
public class FileOutput : IOutput
{
    //public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public void Write(string content)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"AutoFacLog.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
}

private static IContainer Container { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();
            builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
            Container = builder.Build();

            WriteDate();
        }

        public static void WriteDate()
        {
            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var writer = scope.Resolve<IDateWriter>();
                writer.WriteDate();
            }
        }
public class TodayWriter : IDateWriter
{
    private IOutput _output;
    public TodayWriter(IOutput output)
    {
        this._output = output;
    }

    public void WriteDate()
    {
        this._output.Write(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

But from the example the Sample program does not call this Directly my TodayWriter is what is calling my IOutput implementation. How can I switch this back in forth if for one call I want to output to the console and in another I want to write to a file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either need to break up the `IOutput` interface into two different interfaces (`IFileOutput`, `IConsoleOutput`) and then use those where you want to.

Another option is to inject an `IEnumerable<IOutput>` which will give you both implementations of the `IOutput` and then you could write to both if that is desirable.

Comment: So I think i stumpled upon that in the documentation. But would I need two  implementations of TodayWriter then? One that takes an IFileOutput and one that takes an IConsoleOutput? and then use those where i want to?

Comment: It really depends, I'm not sure of what you mean by sometimes wanting to write to one output and sometimes wanting to write to another about, can you provide more detail? 

If you want to write to console or file output at different times within the same class, then you could break it into two interfaces, if you wanted to sometimes *always* write to one of the two outputs, then you could conditionally register the output when you build your container

Comment: I think what I am struggling with is how I change the parameter injection on TodayWriter from file to console. I am never actually calling console output directly but I am calling it through TodayWriter.

Comment: If you are injecting IOutput, then whatever you register as the IOutput when you build your autofac container is what will be injected, if you change the class that you are registering as IOutput, the new implementation will automatically be injected

Comment: change this line:
builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();
to this:
builder.RegisterType<FileOutput>().As<IOutput>();

Comment: Could I have both registered at the same time and dynamically select from the calling program which one I want to use?